# Display KPI status list to home page as a web part in SharePoint 2013

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have a KPI Status indicator list which displays KPI icons and values. I am trying to bring that list to the home page of the current site. But when i add it as a list view web part then it doesn't display anything. How do we display the status list with KPI values and status icon the green, red and yellow in the list view web part in 2013.

Comment: Are you able to find/add the dedicated "Status List" web part (instead of adding a list view web part of your status indicator list)? In SharePoint 2010 it was found in the "Business Data" category of web parts.

Comment: There is not anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can find "Status List" and "Indicator Details" web part in "Business Data" section. Once web part added, configure it with your settings.
[For you Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsJ6Y.png)

Comment: I don't see the status list and indicator list in my business data web part category.  do we need to activate some feature.                                                 However i somehow managed to get the web part in the home page. Edited the status list view page and hidden everything else other than the web part and dislayed it using a page viewer webpart in the home page.

Comment: Yes, i think you need to activate "SharePoint Enterprise Feature". Please refer the below link for Sharepoint features. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/razi/2013/10/28/listing-all-sharepoint-server-2013-features-including-name-title-scope-id-and-description